# React call from class to functional component. Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am calling a functional component from a class component.
This is my functional component,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router";

const UtilsExt = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    navigate('/');

};

export default UtilsExt;
```

I am calling above from a button click event from a class component. When i do that i get this error.

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React hooks can only be called in function components or custom React hooks. In order to use the `navigate` function you'll need to either create a wrapper component or a custom `withNavigate` HOC to pass `navigate` as a prop to your class component.

### Wrapper

```
const MyComponentWithNavigation = props => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return <MyClassComponent {...props} navigate={navigate} />;
};
```

Usage:

```
<Route path="..." element={<MyComponentWithNavigation />} />
```

### HOC

```
const withNavigate = Component => props => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return <Component {...props} navigate={navigate} />;
};
```

Usage:

```
const MyComponentWithNavigation = withNavigation(MyClassComponent);
```

...

```
<Route path="..." element={<MyComponentWithNavigation />} />
```

### Accessing the `navigate` function

In your class component, access `navigate` from props.

```
this.props.navigate("/");
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. It worked!

A follow up question, how do we get to use url prop(and other props) in the new react-router  version 6 and pass it to the element's component like we used to do in the render method?

react-router: V6
<Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>}/>
react-router: V5
<Route exact path="/ds/:id" render={(url) =>                                       
                                            <Header url={url}/>                                                                                   
                                    }/>

Comment: @user3900196 Using the same pattern, `const params = useParams();` for the route params, `const location = useLocation();`, etc... pass these in as props to the component.

Comment: Thanks again. (sorry to ask this question in comment)
A new error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.

Comment: @user3900196 Correct. You only need one router per app.